# static struct in C not changing value

Tags: c, struct

In order to preserve the value of a variable(char array) during execution of program, I have the following code which is used in a bigger code. However I see that the incrementCtr has no effect as the counter gets reset to zero. Can you please point out the right way to use static here?

```
    static typedef struct {
        uint8_t data[8];
    }count_t;

    ......
    static count_t count;

    static void incrementCtr(count_t* count) {
        int i;
        for (i = sizeof(count->data) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (++count->data[i] != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void myroutine{
        .....


        ....

        count_t *counter;
        counter = &count;
        uint32_t len = sizeof(*counter);
        memset(counter ,0,sizeof(*counter));
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("counter->data[%d] = %02X\n", i, counter->data[i]);
        }
        .......
do {
        .......
        incrementCtr(counter);
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("counter->data[%d] = %02X\n", i, counter->data[i]);
         }
        } while (true);
        return 0;
    }
```

The first printf shows all bytes 0 and in the second printf, the byte value gets incremented by 1. But then the counter gets reinitialized to 0 agian :(

Comment: Mixing "count_t count", "count_t* count" and "++count->..." in the same code is not very readable. I suggest renaming your pointer to "count_t* pCouint", for example.

Comment: You mean when you call `myroutine` (that's supposed to be a function, right?) a second time it gets zeroed again? That's because of the `memset` you have there, that's exactly what it does...

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think the lack of Hungarian notation (don't like it personally, but whatever works for you...) is the biggest problem here... Saying `sizeof(*counter)` when you really mean `sizeof(counter->data)/sizeof(*counter->data)` is a lot more serious.

Comment: thanks cha0site. The memset was the killer. I thought I was only looping but then did not see the myroutine being called. I still dont know why you said sizeof(*counter) is wrong. I thought the memset was fine considering I am seroeing the entire struct and sizeof is giving me the size of the struct and not the pointer size

Comment: @cha0site I was not proposing hungarian, but simply not repeating the same variable name. For me "static count_t a" and "static void incrementCtr(count_t* b)" would work, too. I was objecting to the repetition of "count".

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Your code reads "do { ... } while (false);" so this loop is never repeated. So what do you expect ?

Comment: @Ingo that's a mistake - corrected it..

Answer (score 0):

It may occur if you defined `static count_t count;` in header file. In this case you have separate `count` variable for any translation unit (cpp file) which includes this header.

Comment: Thanks. That and memset were the problems. I have corrected them.